# Tensor size does not match classifier's output features number

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to fine-tune model for token classification (named entity recognition) with dataset consisting of 9 unique tokens.

I am mainly interested in 2 models from hugging face transformers library, which are:

1. https://huggingface.co/DeepPavlov/bert-base-bg-cs-pl-ru-cased
2. https://huggingface.co/dkleczek/bert-base-polish-cased-v1

The first one works fine, there is no mismatch between classifier's output features number and tensor size.

```
(classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=9, bias=True)
...
torch.Size([320, 9])
```

Fine-tuning the second one leads to assertion errors which are probably caused by mismatch between classifier's output features number and tensor size.

```
(classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=9, bias=True)
...
torch.Size([336, 2])
```

I have compared both model's parameters and they are entirely the same with exception of `word_embeddings` number which I believe is not relevant in this case.

I would appreciate any tips on how I could solve that issue or indications towards things that I may be missing.

Model initialisation step:

```
    model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
        model_args.model_name_or_path,
        from_tf=bool(".ckpt" in model_args.model_name_or_path),
        config=config,
        cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
        revision=model_args.model_revision,
        use_auth_token=True if model_args.use_auth_token else None,
    )
```

Whole script that I am using - `run_ner.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
# Copyright 2020 The HuggingFace Team All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
"""
Fine-tuning the library models for token classification.
"""
# You can also adapt this script on your own token classification task and datasets. Pointers for this are left as
# comments.

import logging
import os
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
from datasets import ClassLabel, load_dataset, load_metric

import transformers
from transformers import (
    AutoConfig,
    AutoModelForTokenClassification,
    AutoTokenizer,
    DataCollatorForTokenClassification,
    HfArgumentParser,
    PreTrainedTokenizerFast,
    Trainer,
    TrainingArguments,
    set_seed,
)
from transformers.trainer_utils import get_last_checkpoint, is_main_process
from transformers.utils import check_min_version


# Will error if the minimal version of Transformers is not installed. Remove at your own risks.
#check_min_version("4.5.0.dev0")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@dataclass
class ModelArguments:
    """
    Arguments pertaining to which model/config/tokenizer we are going to fine-tune from.
    """

    model_name_or_path: str = field(
        metadata={"help": "Path to pretrained model or model identifier from huggingface.co/models"}
    )
    config_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "Pretrained config name or path if not the same as model_name"}
    )
    tokenizer_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "Pretrained tokenizer name or path if not the same as model_name"}
    )
    cache_dir: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "Where do you want to store the pretrained models downloaded from huggingface.co"},
    )
    model_revision: str = field(
        default="main",
        metadata={"help": "The specific model version to use (can be a branch name, tag name or commit id)."},
    )
    use_auth_token: bool = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={
            "help": "Will use the token generated when running `transformers-cli login` (necessary to use this script "
            "with private models)."
        },
    )


@dataclass
class DataTrainingArguments:
    """
    Arguments pertaining to what data we are going to input our model for training and eval.
    """

    task_name: Optional[str] = field(default="ner", metadata={"help": "The name of the task (ner, pos...)."})
    dataset_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "The name of the dataset to use (via the datasets library)."}
    )
    dataset_config_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "The configuration name of the dataset to use (via the datasets library)."}
    )
    train_file: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None, metadata={"help": "The input training data file (a csv or JSON file)."}
    )
    validation_file: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "An optional input evaluation data file to evaluate on (a csv or JSON file)."},
    )
    test_file: Optional[str] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "An optional input test data file to predict on (a csv or JSON file)."},
    )
    overwrite_cache: bool = field(
        default=False, metadata={"help": "Overwrite the cached training and evaluation sets"}
    )
    preprocessing_num_workers: Optional[int] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={"help": "The number of processes to use for the preprocessing."},
    )
    pad_to_max_length: bool = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={
            "help": "Whether to pad all samples to model maximum sentence length. "
            "If False, will pad the samples dynamically when batching to the maximum length in the batch. More "
            "efficient on GPU but very bad for TPU."
        },
    )
    max_train_samples: Optional[int] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "help": "For debugging purposes or quicker training, truncate the number of training examples to this "
            "value if set."
        },
    )
    max_val_samples: Optional[int] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "help": "For debugging purposes or quicker training, truncate the number of validation examples to this "
            "value if set."
        },
    )
    max_test_samples: Optional[int] = field(
        default=None,
        metadata={
            "help": "For debugging purposes or quicker training, truncate the number of test examples to this "
            "value if set."
        },
    )
    label_all_tokens: bool = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={
            "help": "Whether to put the label for one word on all tokens of generated by that word or just on the "
            "one (in which case the other tokens will have a padding index)."
        },
    )
    return_entity_level_metrics: bool = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={"help": "Whether to return all the entity levels during evaluation or just the overall ones."},
    )

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.dataset_name is None and self.train_file is None and self.validation_file is None:
            raise ValueError("Need either a dataset name or a training/validation file.")
        else:
            if self.train_file is not None:
                extension = self.train_file.split(".")[-1]
                assert extension in ["csv", "json"], "`train_file` should be a csv or a json file."
            if self.validation_file is not None:
                extension = self.validation_file.split(".")[-1]
                assert extension in ["csv", "json"], "`validation_file` should be a csv or a json file."
        self.task_name = self.task_name.lower()


def main():
    # See all possible arguments in src/transformers/training_args.py
    # or by passing the --help flag to this script.
    # We now keep distinct sets of args, for a cleaner separation of concerns.

    parser = HfArgumentParser((ModelArguments, DataTrainingArguments, TrainingArguments))
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1].endswith(".json"):
        # If we pass only one argument to the script and it's the path to a json file,
        # let's parse it to get our arguments.
        model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_json_file(json_file=os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1]))
    else:
        model_args, data_args, training_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()

    # Detecting last checkpoint.
    last_checkpoint = None
    if os.path.isdir(training_args.output_dir) and training_args.do_train and not training_args.overwrite_output_dir:
        last_checkpoint = get_last_checkpoint(training_args.output_dir)
        if last_checkpoint is None and len(os.listdir(training_args.output_dir)) > 0:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Output directory ({training_args.output_dir}) already exists and is not empty. "
                "Use --overwrite_output_dir to overcome."
            )
        elif last_checkpoint is not None:
            logger.info(
                f"Checkpoint detected, resuming training at {last_checkpoint}. To avoid this behavior, change "
                "the `--output_dir` or add `--overwrite_output_dir` to train from scratch."
            )

    # Setup logging
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s -   %(message)s",
        datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
        handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)],
    )
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO if is_main_process(training_args.local_rank) else logging.WARN)

    # Log on each process the small summary:
    logger.warning(
        f"Process rank: {training_args.local_rank}, device: {training_args.device}, n_gpu: {training_args.n_gpu}"
        + f"distributed training: {bool(training_args.local_rank != -1)}, 16-bits training: {training_args.fp16}"
    )
    # Set the verbosity to info of the Transformers logger (on main process only):
    if is_main_process(training_args.local_rank):
        transformers.utils.logging.set_verbosity_info()
        transformers.utils.logging.enable_default_handler()
        transformers.utils.logging.enable_explicit_format()
    logger.info("Training/evaluation parameters %s", training_args)

    # Set seed before initializing model.
    set_seed(training_args.seed)

    # Get the datasets: you can either provide your own CSV/JSON/TXT training and evaluation files (see below)
    # or just provide the name of one of the public datasets available on the hub at https://huggingface.co/datasets/
    # (the dataset will be downloaded automatically from the datasets Hub).
    #
    # For CSV/JSON files, this script will use the column called 'text' or the first column if no column called
    # 'text' is found. You can easily tweak this behavior (see below).
    #
    # In distributed training, the load_dataset function guarantee that only one local process can concurrently
    # download the dataset.
    if data_args.dataset_name is not None:
        # Downloading and loading a dataset from the hub.
        datasets = load_dataset(data_args.dataset_name, data_args.dataset_config_name)
    else:
        data_files = {}
        if data_args.train_file is not None:
            data_files["train"] = data_args.train_file
        if data_args.validation_file is not None:
            data_files["validation"] = data_args.validation_file
        if data_args.test_file is not None:
            data_files["test"] = data_args.test_file
        extension = data_args.train_file.split(".")[-1]
        datasets = load_dataset(extension, data_files=data_files)
    # See more about loading any type of standard or custom dataset (from files, python dict, pandas DataFrame, etc) at
    # https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading_datasets.html.

    if training_args.do_train:
        column_names = datasets["train"].column_names
        features = datasets["train"].features
    else:
        column_names = datasets["validation"].column_names
        features = datasets["validation"].features
    text_column_name = "tokens" if "tokens" in column_names else column_names[0]
    label_column_name = (
        f"{data_args.task_name}_tags" if f"{data_args.task_name}_tags" in column_names else column_names[1]
    )

    # In the event the labels are not a `Sequence[ClassLabel]`, we will need to go through the dataset to get the
    # unique labels.
    def get_label_list(labels):
        unique_labels = set()
        for label in labels:
            unique_labels = unique_labels | set(label)
        label_list = list(unique_labels)
        label_list.sort()
        return label_list

    if isinstance(features[label_column_name].feature, ClassLabel):
        label_list = features[label_column_name].feature.names
        # No need to convert the labels since they are already ints.
        label_to_id = {i: i for i in range(len(label_list))}
    else:
        label_list = get_label_list(datasets["train"][label_column_name])
        label_to_id = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(label_list)}
    num_labels = len(label_list)

    label2id = {label: i for i, label in enumerate(label_list)}
    print("\nlabel_list\n", label_list)
    print("\nlabel_to_id\n", label_to_id)
    print("\nnum_labels\n", num_labels)

    # label2id=label_to_id,
    id2label={id: label for label, id in label_to_id.items()}
    #print(label2id)
    #print(id2label)

    
    # Load pretrained model and tokenizer
    #
    # Distributed training:
    # The .from_pretrained methods guarantee that only one local process can concurrently
    # download model & vocab.
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
        model_args.config_name if model_args.config_name else model_args.model_name_or_path,
        num_labels=num_labels,

        label2id=label_to_id,
        id2label={id: label for label, id in label_to_id.items()},

        finetuning_task=data_args.task_name,
        cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
        revision=model_args.model_revision,
        use_auth_token=True if model_args.use_auth_token else None,
    )
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_args.tokenizer_name if model_args.tokenizer_name else model_args.model_name_or_path,
        cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
        use_fast=True,
        revision=model_args.model_revision,
        use_auth_token=True if model_args.use_auth_token else None,
    )
    model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
        model_args.model_name_or_path,
        from_tf=bool(".ckpt" in model_args.model_name_or_path),
        #from_tf=True,
        config=config,
        cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
        revision=model_args.model_revision,
        use_auth_token=True if model_args.use_auth_token else None,
    )

    # Tokenizer check: this script requires a fast tokenizer.
    if not isinstance(tokenizer, PreTrainedTokenizerFast):
        raise ValueError(
            "This example script only works for models that have a fast tokenizer. Checkout the big table of models "
            "at https://huggingface.co/transformers/index.html#bigtable to find the model types that meet this "
            "requirement"
        )

    # Preprocessing the dataset
    # Padding strategy
    padding = "max_length" if data_args.pad_to_max_length else False

    # Tokenize all texts and align the labels with them.
    def tokenize_and_align_labels(examples):
        # print("examples\n", examples)
        tokenized_inputs = tokenizer(
            examples[text_column_name],
            padding=padding,
            truncation=True,
            # We use this argument because the texts in our dataset are lists of words (with a label for each word).
            is_split_into_words=True,
        )
        labels = []
        for i, label in enumerate(examples[label_column_name]):
            # print("\nlabel in enumerate(examples[label_column_name])\n", label)
            word_ids = tokenized_inputs.word_ids(batch_index=i)
            previous_word_idx = None
            label_ids = []
            for word_idx in word_ids:
                # Special tokens have a word id that is None. We set the label to -100 so they are automatically
                # ignored in the loss function.
                if word_idx is None:
                    label_ids.append(-100)
                # We set the label for the first token of each word.
                elif word_idx != previous_word_idx:
                    label_ids.append(label_to_id[label[word_idx]])
                    # label_ids.append(label2id[label[word_idx]])

                # For the other tokens in a word, we set the label to either the current label or -100, depending on
                # the label_all_tokens flag.
                else:
                    label_ids.append(label_to_id[label[word_idx]] if data_args.label_all_tokens else -100)
                    # label_ids.append(label2id[label[word_idx]] if data_args.label_all_tokens else -100)

                previous_word_idx = word_idx

            labels.append(label_ids)
        tokenized_inputs["labels"] = labels
        # print("label_to_id\n", label_to_id)
        # print("\n\n tokenized_inputs\n", tokenized_inputs)
        return tokenized_inputs

    if training_args.do_train:
        if "train" not in datasets:
            raise ValueError("--do_train requires a train dataset")
        train_dataset = datasets["train"]
        if data_args.max_train_samples is not None:
            train_dataset = train_dataset.select(range(data_args.max_train_samples))
        train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
            tokenize_and_align_labels,
            batched=True,
            num_proc=data_args.preprocessing_num_workers,
            load_from_cache_file=not data_args.overwrite_cache,
        )

    if training_args.do_eval:
        if "validation" not in datasets:
            raise ValueError("--do_eval requires a validation dataset")
        eval_dataset = datasets["validation"]
        if data_args.max_val_samples is not None:
            eval_dataset = eval_dataset.select(range(data_args.max_val_samples))
        eval_dataset = eval_dataset.map(
            tokenize_and_align_labels,
            batched=True,
            num_proc=data_args.preprocessing_num_workers,
            load_from_cache_file=not data_args.overwrite_cache,
        )

    if training_args.do_predict:
        if "test" not in datasets:
            raise ValueError("--do_predict requires a test dataset")
        test_dataset = datasets["test"]
        if data_args.max_test_samples is not None:
            test_dataset = test_dataset.select(range(data_args.max_test_samples))
        test_dataset = test_dataset.map(
            tokenize_and_align_labels,
            batched=True,
            num_proc=data_args.preprocessing_num_workers,
            load_from_cache_file=not data_args.overwrite_cache,
        )

    # Data collator
    data_collator = DataCollatorForTokenClassification(tokenizer, pad_to_multiple_of=8 if training_args.fp16 else None)

    # Metrics
    metric = load_metric("seqeval")

    def compute_metrics(p):
        predictions, labels = p
        predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

        # Remove ignored index (special tokens)
        true_predictions = [
            [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
            for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
        ]
        true_labels = [
            [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
            for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
        ]

        results = metric.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
        if data_args.return_entity_level_metrics:
            # Unpack nested dictionaries
            final_results = {}
            for key, value in results.items():
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    for n, v in value.items():
                        final_results[f"{key}_{n}"] = v
                else:
                    final_results[key] = value
            return final_results
        else:
            return {
                "precision": results["overall_precision"],
                "recall": results["overall_recall"],
                "f1": results["overall_f1"],
                "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
            }

    # Initialize our Trainer
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=train_dataset if training_args.do_train else None,
        eval_dataset=eval_dataset if training_args.do_eval else None,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    )

    print("\nmodel parameters\n", model.parameters)

    # Training
    if training_args.do_train:
        if last_checkpoint is not None:
            checkpoint = last_checkpoint
        elif os.path.isdir(model_args.model_name_or_path):
            checkpoint = model_args.model_name_or_path
        else:
            checkpoint = None
        train_result = trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=checkpoint)
        metrics = train_result.metrics
        trainer.save_model()  # Saves the tokenizer too for easy upload

        max_train_samples = (
            data_args.max_train_samples if data_args.max_train_samples is not None else len(train_dataset)
        )
        metrics["train_samples"] = min(max_train_samples, len(train_dataset))

        trainer.log_metrics("train", metrics)
        trainer.save_metrics("train", metrics)
        trainer.save_state()

    # Evaluation
    if training_args.do_eval:
        logger.info("*** Evaluate ***")

        metrics = trainer.evaluate()

        max_val_samples = data_args.max_val_samples if data_args.max_val_samples is not None else len(eval_dataset)
        metrics["eval_samples"] = min(max_val_samples, len(eval_dataset))

        trainer.log_metrics("eval", metrics)
        trainer.save_metrics("eval", metrics)

    # Predict
    if training_args.do_predict:
        logger.info("*** Predict ***")

        predictions, labels, metrics = trainer.predict(test_dataset)
        predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

        # Remove ignored index (special tokens)
        true_predictions = [
            [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
            for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
        ]

        trainer.log_metrics("test", metrics)
        trainer.save_metrics("test", metrics)

        # Save predictions
        output_test_predictions_file = os.path.join(training_args.output_dir, "test_predictions.txt")
        if trainer.is_world_process_zero():
            with open(output_test_predictions_file, "w") as writer:
                for prediction in true_predictions:
                    writer.write(" ".join(prediction) + "\n")


def _mp_fn(index):
    # For xla_spawn (TPUs)
    main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`environment.yml`

```
name: test_3_1
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=1_llvm
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - ca-certificates=2020.12.5=ha878542_0
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py38h578d9bd_1
  - cudatoolkit=11.1.1=h6406543_8
  - ffmpeg=4.3=hf484d3e_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=h0708190_1
  - gmp=6.2.1=h58526e2_0
  - gnutls=3.6.13=h85f3911_1
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - lame=3.100=h7f98852_1001
  - lcms2=2.11=h396b838_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
  - libgcc-ng=9.3.0=h2828fa1_18
  - libiconv=1.16=h516909a_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=h21135ba_2
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.3.0=h6de172a_18
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_1
  - libuv=1.41.0=h7f98852_0
  - llvm-openmp=11.0.1=h4bd325d_0
  - lz4-c=1.9.3=h9c3ff4c_0
  - mkl=2020.4=h726a3e6_304
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py38h1e0a361_2
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0=py38h5c078b8_1
  - mkl_random=1.2.0=py38hc5bc63f_1
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
  - nettle=3.6=he412f7d_0
  - ninja=1.10.2=h4bd325d_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.2=py38hfa32c7d_0
  - olefile=0.46=pyh9f0ad1d_1
  - openh264=2.1.1=h780b84a_0
  - openssl=1.1.1j=h7f98852_0
  - pillow=8.1.2=py38he98fc37_0
  - pip=21.0.1=py38h06a4308_0
  - python=3.8.8=hdb3f193_4
  - python_abi=3.8=1_cp38
  - pytorch=1.8.0=py3.8_cuda11.1_cudnn8.0.5_0
  - readline=8.1=h27cfd23_0
  - setuptools=52.0.0=py38h06a4308_0
  - six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - sqlite=3.35.1=hdfb4753_0
  - tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
  - torchaudio=0.8.0=py38
  - torchvision=0.9.0=py38_cu111
  - typing_extensions=3.7.4.3=py_0
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.4.9=ha95c52a_0
  - pip:
    - chardet==4.0.0
    - click==7.1.2
    - datasets==1.4.1
    - dill==0.3.3
    - filelock==3.0.12
    - fsspec==0.8.7
    - huggingface-hub==0.0.2
    - idna==2.10
    - joblib==1.0.1
    - multiprocess==0.70.11.1
    - numpy==1.20.1
    - packaging==20.9
    - pandas==1.2.3
    - pyarrow==3.0.0
    - pyparsing==2.4.7
    - python-dateutil==2.8.1
    - pytz==2021.1
    - regex==2020.11.13
    - requests==2.25.1
    - sacremoses==0.0.43
    - scikit-learn==0.24.1
    - scipy==1.6.1
    - seqeval==1.2.2
    - threadpoolctl==2.1.0
    - tokenizers==0.10.1
    - tqdm==4.49.0
    - transformers==4.4.1
    - urllib3==1.26.4
    - xxhash==2.0.0
```

1 line sample of dataset - `single_line.json`:
**Below sample consists 3 unique labels instead of 9.**

```json
{"words": ["Astronomię", "można", "inaczej", "określić", "jako", "naukę", "o", "wszelkich", "obiektach", "i", "zjawiskach", "znajdujących", "się", "poza", "Ziemią", "."], "ner": ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "B-LOC", "I-LOC", "O"]}
```

Execution calls:

1. Works.

```sh
python run_ner.py \
 --model_name_or_path "DeepPavlov/bert-base-bg-cs-pl-ru-cased" \
 --train_file single_line.json \
 --validation_file single_line.json \
 --test_file single_line.json \
 --do_train \
 --do_eval \
 --do_predict \
 --output_dir model_test_deeppavlov \
 --save_steps 50000 \
 --num_train_epochs 1
```

2. Crashes.

```sh
python run_ner.py \
 --model_name_or_path bert-base-polish-cased-v1 \
 --train_file single_line.json \
 --validation_file single_line.json \
 --test_file single_line.json \
 --do_train \
 --do_eval \
 --do_predict \
 --output_dir model_test_polish_bert \
 --save_steps 50000 \
 --num_train_epochs 1
```

In order to use `bert-base-polish-cased-v1` model, it may require to be downloaded.

```sh
git clone https://huggingface.co/dkleczek/bert-base-polish-cased-v1
```

Comment: How do you initialize your model during finetuning?

Comment: Pretty much like here:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/token-classification/run_ner.py

Comment: Please do not give me a link to some script and expect me to select or guess what you might have done. It is often the case that answerers waste their time because the OP did something completely different. [Every question on SO is supposed to be self-sustained.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/should-posts-be-self-contained)

Comment: Thank you and sorry, added what I suppose is model initialisation.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with this [code](https://pastebin.com/Sc6LBDme). Maybe you do something after the interference? In case you are using the script as it is, it also acceptable to post the parameters you use and give a small sample of your data (can be artificial) that leads to the issue.

Comment: Supplied question with everything what is needed to reproduce my case. Thank you.
 Regarding the interference: I think the tuning crashes at the very first batch of examples. When I adjusted sample data for it to have only 2 unique labels, the tuning didn't crash - it progressed as it should.

Comment: The second one crashes for me as well but with a different error. I can not even create a BertModel from the files of the git repository. But the author of the repository has uploaded the model to the model hub and this version works. Can you try it with ` --model_name_or_path "dkleczek/bert-base-polish-cased-v1"`?

Comment: Wow. It worked. I had troubles with pointing to that model through model hub call and that's why I used to simply download it, but in this case it somehow worked without preceeding download through GIT LFS. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Updating `transformers` library from **4.4.1** to **4.6.1** solved it.

This issue contains simmilar errors to the ones I've encountered and points to that trivial solution: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/2719.